# Server Core Installation of Windows Server 2012

Tags: powershell, server-core

I am new to server core installations so to understand them better I created a VM through Hyper V, installed Windows Server 2012 as Server Core. Accessed the computer and kept trying to run the Netdom.exe RenameComputer function.

I switched over to my main server and then switched back and I have lost the Command Line prompt.

How do I get this back? Cntrl+Alt+Del do not seem to have an option to launch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press CTRL+ALT+DELETE, click Start Task Manager, click File, click Run, and then type cmd.exe. Alternatively, you can log off and log back on.

Comment: Got it, I tried Task Manager but had to hit the expand details link for the File Menu option to appear! Thanks

Comment: I tried logging off and on but that just gave me the black screen again.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+Shift+Escape to run Task Manager. Choose Expand Details, then File | Run | cmd.exe.

Or File | Run | powershell.exe if you want PowerShell instead of Command Prompt (which you should :-).